# Count keystrokes used in character typing

Tags: php, python, keystroke

I am trying to create an application which calculates the typing speed. I want to know if there is any PHP or python library which returns the number of keystrokes for different languages because in some languages characters are typed using a combination of keys.

Thanks

Comment: PHP is server side, what you want is client side. Use Javascript

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend calculating your keystrokes at the front-end(client-side).

For example you can use JQuery's [keyup()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_keyup.asp) to trigger an event everytime you release a key stroke.